# Pinned memory in Nvidia CUDA

Tags: cuda

I'm writing matrix addition program for GPUs using Streams and obviously pinned memory.So I allocated 3 matrices in pinned memory but after particular dimensions it shows API error 2:out of memory.My RAM is 4GB but i'm not able to use beyond 800MB.Is there any way by which we can control this upper limit?
My sys config:
nVidia GEForce 9800GTX
Intel core 2 Quad
For streamed execution code looks as follows

```
(int i=0;i<no_of_streams;i++)
    {
       cudaMemcpyAsync(device_a+i*(n/no_of_streams),hAligned_on_host_a+i*(n/no_of_streams),nbytes/no_of_streams,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,streams[i]);
       cudaMemcpyAsync(device_b+i*(n/no_of_streams),hAligned_on_host_b+i*(n/no_of_streams),nbytes/no_of_streams,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,streams[i]);
       cudaMemcpyAsync(device_c+i*(n/no_of_streams),hAligned_on_host_c+i*(n/no_of_streams),nbytes/no_of_streams,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,streams[i]);
       matrixAddition<<<blocks,threads,0,streams[i]>>>(device_a+i*(n/no_of_streams),device_b+i*(n/no_of_streams),device_c+i*(n/no_of_streams));
       cudaMemcpyAsync(hAligned_on_host_a+i*(n/no_of_streams),device_a+i*(n/no_of_streams),nbytes/no_of_streams,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost,streams[i]);
       cudaMemcpyAsync(hAligned_on_host_b+i*(n/no_of_streamss),device_b+i*(n/no_of_streams),nbytes/no_of_streams,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost,streams[i]);
       cudaMemcpyAsync(hAligned_on_host_c+i*(n/no_of_streams),device_c+i*(n/no_of_streams),nbytes/no_of_streams,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost,streams[i]));

    }
```

Comment: Could be a bunch of reasons ranging from fragmented memory to bad code. Would be nice to see what you are doing to actually make an useful suggestion.

Comment: Code flow is as follows
`2 streams created
 for each stream
      cudamemcpy(half portion of array,hostToDevice)
      kernel launch
      cudaMemcpy(halfportion of array,DeviceToHost)

Nothing special program is working fine with performance difference,I just want to have more pinned memory is it happening because GPUs global memory is around 1GB?

Comment: Put any code by editing the question.

Comment: What operating system (and is it 32-bit or 64-bit)?

Answer (score 1):

So, you haven't specified if this happens after the cudaMalloc or the cudaHostAlloc function calls.

Pinned memory is a limited resource. Any memory defined as being in pinned memory must always be in RAM. As such, that leaves less room in RAM for other system applications. This means, you can't have 4GB of pinned memory if you have 4GB of RAM, or else nothing else could run.

800MB might be a system imposed limit. Considering it's a quarter of your RAM, it might be a reasonable limit. It is also quite close to the size of your global memory. A failure on the card wouldn't translate to a failure on the host, so if it's complaining without having to run something like cudaGetLastError, it's probably a problem on the host.

Sorry I don't know specifics of increasing your pinned memory limit.

Comment: But i ran same experiment on Tesla C2070 which has 4GB global memory ..while running same program where each matrix takes 256MB memory program is being abruptly killed..is it because of same problem?

Comment: It looks like it might not be the card then.

Try adding cudaThreadSynchronize and cudaGetLastError calls after each allocation and you should see which one is failing.